# Extract data from PDF and export to excel

Tags: python, excel

few months I make script for automate the next process.

1. Make list of .pdf files inside folder.
2. Extract data from each pdf file
3. Save extracted data in excel table

The script work prefect when process up to 15 pdf files but if I try with more don't work. I think crash in process number 3 but I can not be sure.

I write checkpoints ( print number of files found, print data extracted, etc....) but for be able to save nonbreaking space data I need put this code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')
```

When I put this lines I not see anything in python shell so I don't know when script crash.

I think maybe could be something about memory but I need your help.

I apreciate if you can check my code and give me advice

Thanks,

All my script:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')
import os
from glob import glob

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re
import xlsxwriter
import time




def find_ext(dr, ext):
    return glob(path.join(dr,"*.{}".format(ext)))  

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
files = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(('.pdf','.PDF')), files)

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    fstr = ''
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,    password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

        str = retstr.getvalue()
        fstr += str

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return fstr

fecha_de_hoy =(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
fecha_de_hoy = re.sub("/", "-", fecha_de_hoy)

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()



# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0


# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.

worksheet.write(row, col, "FECHA")
worksheet.write(row, col + 1, "CLIENTE")
worksheet.write(row, col + 2, "PROVEEDOR" )
worksheet.write(row, col + 3, "REF. CLIENTE" )
worksheet.write(row, col + 4, "REMITENTE")
worksheet.write(row, col + 5, "DESTINATARIO")
worksheet.write(row, col + 6, "DIRECCION DEST.")
worksheet.write(row, col + 7, "CODIGO POSTAL DEST.")
worksheet.write(row, col + 8, "POBLACION DEST.")
worksheet.write(row, col + 9, "PROVINCIA DEST.")
worksheet.write(row, col + 10, "Nº BULTOS")
worksheet.write(row, col + 11, "PESO")
worksheet.write(row, col + 12, "COSTE")
worksheet.write(row, col + 13, "PVP")
worksheet.write(row, col + 14, "E-mail CONFIRMACIÓN")

row+=1

e = len(files)
lengthlist = e
w=0
print e

while w < lengthlist:

    print w
    print files[w]

    factura = files[w]

    string = convert_pdf_to_txt(factura)


    txtList = convert_pdf_to_txt(factura).splitlines()
    destinatarioIdx, direcionNumIdx, codigoNumIdx, poblacionIdx, provinciaIdx, pedidoIdx, bultosIdx = -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1

    for idx, line in enumerate(txtList):
        if line == "Destino MercancÃ­a":
            destinatarioIdx = idx +1
            direcionNumIdx = idx +2
            codigoNumIdx = idx +3  
            poblacionIdx = idx +3
            provinciaIdx = idx +4


        if line == "NÂº de Pedido":
            pedidoIdx = idx +1

        if "Bultos" in line:
            bultosIdx = idx + 2



    nombre_destinatario = txtList[destinatarioIdx] if destinatarioIdx != -1 else ''
    nombre_destinatario = re.sub("Ã‰", "É", nombre_destinatario)
    direccion_destinatario = txtList[direcionNumIdx] if direcionNumIdx != -1 else ''
    codigo_destinatario = txtList[codigoNumIdx] if codigoNumIdx != -1 else ''
    codigo_destinatario = re.sub("\D", "", codigo_destinatario)
    poblacion_destinatario = txtList[poblacionIdx] if poblacionIdx != -1 else ''
    poblacion_destinatario = re.sub("[0-9]", "", poblacion_destinatario)
    poblacion_destinatario = re.sub(r"\s+", "", poblacion_destinatario, flags=re.UNICODE)
    provincia_destinatario = txtList[provinciaIdx] if provinciaIdx != -1 else ''
    pedido_destinatario = txtList[pedidoIdx] if pedidoIdx != -1 else ''
    bultos_destinatario = txtList[bultosIdx] if bultosIdx != -1 else ''
    bultos_destinatario = re.sub(r"\s+", "", bultos_destinatario, flags=re.UNICODE)

    #ARREGLAR EXCEPCIONES

    '''for idx, line in enumerate(txtList):
        if line == "Destino MercancÃ­a":
            destinatarioIdx = idx +1
            direcionNumIdx = idx +2
            codigoNumIdx = idx +3

            if codigoNumIdx < 1000:
                direcion1 = idx +2
                direccion2 = idx +3
                direcionNumIdx = (direcion1, direccion2)
                codigoNumIdx = idx +4
                poblacionIdx = idx +4
                provinciaIdx = idx +5'''

    print "Nombre Destinatario"
    print nombre_destinatario
    print "Direccion destinatario"
    print direccion_destinatario
    print "codigo destinatario"
    print codigo_destinatario
    print "poblacion destinatario"
    print poblacion_destinatario
    print "Provincia destinatario"
    print provincia_destinatario
    print "Nº pedido destinatario"
    print pedido_destinatario
    print "Nº bultos envío"
    print bultos_destinatario

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.

    worksheet.write(row, col, fecha_de_hoy)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, "SIDAC")
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, "PROVEEDOR" )
    worksheet.write(row, col + 3, pedido_destinatario )
    worksheet.write(row, col + 4, "SIDAC")
    worksheet.write(row, col + 5, nombre_destinatario)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 6, direccion_destinatario)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 7, codigo_destinatario)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 8, poblacion_destinatario)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 9, provincia_destinatario)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 10, bultos_destinatario)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 11, "PESO")
    worksheet.write(row, col + 12, "COSTE")
    worksheet.write(row, col + 13, "PVP")
    worksheet.write(row, col + 14, "trafico@buendialogistica.com")




    w+=1
    row+=1


workbook.close()
```